# mssql -default value for input argument in user defined function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, default-value

In Microsoft SQL Server 2016, created a function with default argument, but it is not working as expected.

When calling `select dbo.myTest(2)`, it is giving error:

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function dbo.myTest.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myTest(@num1 INT, @num2 int = 1 )
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

   RETURN @num2

END
```

I am expecting to call the function with 1 argument also, What is it I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You defined two function paramters. For function execution, you must add two parameter to function. Not one of them. Must be two..

Comment: that is why am giving default value for argument @num2 int = 1, so that I do not have to pass the value...